# Set a request timeout

Tags: python, celery

I want to set a time limit to a request, so that, if the queue is down, the client doesn't have to wait a long time to get a connection error. For now, when I make a request to queue that is down, the applications hangs lots of time before I get an exceptio.

I tried to set time_limit, soft_time_limit, timeout and soft_timeout in the client requests but none of them worked.

How I do set a timeout that a request can wait to get a response, before it can fail?

Here is the code that I use to call.

```
task = clusterWorking.apply_async(queue=q, soft_time_limit=2, time_limit=5)
task = clusterWorking.apply_async(queue=q, timeout=1, soft_timeout=1)
```

Here is the server code.

```
@task(name='manager.pingdaemon.clusterWorking')
def clusterWorking():
    return "up"
```

Comment: I think I have found. This is the answer:

   task = clusterWorking.apply_async(queue=q)
   result = task.wait(5)

If it doesn`t get an answer in 5 sep, I get a timeout exception.

If you know another solution, please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use get(timeout)
http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/celery.result.html?highlight=get#celery.result.ResultSet.get

```
try:
    task = clusterWorking.apply_async(queue=q).get(5)
except TimeoutError:
    pass
```